# How to change the minimum swipe distance in Android Gallery?

Tags: android, gallery, swipe, minimum, onfling

I have a class that extends `Gallery` called **MyGallery** and I have a set of bitmaps to show in a MyGallery widget. 
In order to swipe only one item per gesture, I had to override the `onFling()` so it won't call the `super.onFling()`. The problem is that in order to change item, I have to swipe more than 50% of the screen size and it's bothering me. I did a search but I didn't find any ways to change this minimum limit. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MotionEvent object to handle the minimum and maximum Swipe distances.

Calculate the swipe distance using the MotionEvent object i.e.., event.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float rawX = 0.0f, dist;
    switch (event.getAction()) 
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        rawX = event.getX();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        dist = event.getX() - rawX;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```